# Uncheck one of the checkboxes, and the data from report analysis also will hide one

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, dropdown

Please see image, currently the checked checkbox from issue and report analysis data are from table or database.

My question is how if I unchecked one of the checkboxes, the data from report analysis will hide one. Then if I checked one more checkbox it will add one more details for report analysis to be keyed in. I try below code, but unsuccessfully.

[image]

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Add an event listener for each checkbox
  var issueCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="selectedIssues[]"]');
  issueCheckboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      showAnalysisDropdowns();
    });
  });

  // Initialize the display on page load
  showAnalysisDropdowns();
});

function showAnalysisDropdowns() {
  var issueCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="selectedIssues[]"]');
  var analysisContainer = document.getElementById('analysisContainer');
  var doContainer = document.getElementById('doContainer');

  analysisContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing "Report Analysis" content
  doContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing "doNo" and "doQuantity" content

  var analysis_data = [
    <?php
                $analysis = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT analysis_desc, analysis_value FROM list_report_analysis where analysis_status='1'");
                $analysisOptions = array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($analysis)) {
                    $analysisOptions[] = $row['analysis_desc'] . ',' . $row['analysis_value'];
                }
                echo '"' . implode('", "', $analysisOptions) . '"';
                ?>
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < issueCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    if (issueCheckboxes[i].checked) {
      // Create "Report Analysis" dropdowns as before
      var select = document.createElement("select");
      select.name = "analysis_data[]";
      select.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select Report Analysis</option>';

      for (var j = 0; j < analysis_data.length; j++) {
        var parts = analysis_data[j].split(',');
        var desc = parts[0];
        var value = parts[1];
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = value;
        option.text = desc;
        option.setAttribute('data-analysis-desc', desc);
        select.add(option);
      }

      var sampleNoInput = document.createElement("input");
      sampleNoInput.type = "text";
      sampleNoInput.name = "analysis_sampleNo[]";
      sampleNoInput.placeholder = "Sample No";

      var resultInput = document.createElement("input");
      resultInput.type = "text";
      resultInput.name = "analysis_result[]";
      resultInput.placeholder = "Result";

      var analysisTotalInput = document.createElement("input");
      analysisTotalInput.type = "text";
      analysisTotalInput.name = "analysis_total[]";
      analysisTotalInput.placeholder = "Total Exceed";
      analysisTotalInput.readOnly = true;
      analysisTotalInput.value = '';

      analysisContainer.appendChild(select);
      analysisContainer.appendChild(sampleNoInput);
      analysisContainer.appendChild(resultInput);
      analysisContainer.appendChild(analysisTotalInput);
      analysisContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
  }

  // Add the "Calculate" button
  var calculateButton = document.createElement("button");
  calculateButton.textContent = "Calculate";
  calculateButton.type = "button";
  calculateButton.onclick = calculateAnalysisTotal;
  analysisContainer.appendChild(calculateButton);
  analysisContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

  // Hide analysisContainer if no checkboxes are checked
  analysisContainer.style.display = (document.querySelector('input[name="selectedIssues[]"]:checked') ? 'block' : 'none');
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b> Issue : </b></td>
    <td>
      <?php
        // Select issue_ids related to the specified complaintId
        $sql = "SELECT issue_id FROM tblccrs_details WHERE complaintId='" . $_GET['cid'] . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        $issueIdsFromDatabase = array(); // Initialize an array to store issue_ids

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $explodedList = explode(',', $row['issue_id']);

            // Add the issue_ids to the array
            $issueIdsFromDatabase = array_merge($issueIdsFromDatabase, $explodedList);
        }

        // Remove duplicates from the array
        $issueIdsFromDatabase = array_unique($issueIdsFromDatabase);

        $issue = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM list_issue_ts where issue_ts_status='1'");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($issue)) {
            $issueId = $row['issue_id'];
            $issueDesc = $row['issue_ts_desc'];

            // Check if the issue_id is in the selected issues array
            $isChecked = in_array($issueId, $issueIdsFromDatabase);

            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="selectedIssues[]" value="' . $issueId . '" ' . ($isChecked ? 'checked' : '') . ' onchange="showAnalysisDropdowns()"> ' . $issueDesc . '<br>';
        }
        ?>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr height="50">
    <td colspan="2"> <b>Report Analysis : </b> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <?php
        $a = 1;
        $sql = "SELECT analysis_desc, analysis_sampleNo, analysis_result, analysis_total FROM tblccrs_report_analysis WHERE complaintId='" . $_GET['cid'] . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        ?>

        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <div class="analysis-container">
          <label for="analysisData<?php echo $a; ?>">
                    <?php echo $a ?>. <?php //echo $row['analysis_desc']; ?>
                </label>
          <select name="analysisData<?php echo $a; ?>" onchange="calculateAnalysisTotal(this)">
            <!-- Populate options dynamically as before -->
            <?php
                    $analysisDesc = $row['analysis_desc'];
                    $analysisValue = $row['analysis_value'];

                    $allAnalysisQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT analysis_desc, analysis_value FROM list_report_analysis WHERE analysis_status='1'";
                    $allAnalysisResult = mysqli_query($con, $allAnalysisQuery);

                    while ($descRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allAnalysisResult)) {
                        $selected = ($descRow['analysis_desc'] == $analysisDesc) ? "selected" : "";
                        echo '<option value="' . $descRow['analysis_desc'] . '" data-analysis-value="' . $descRow['analysis_value'] . '" ' . $selected . '>'
                            . $descRow['analysis_desc'] . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
          </select>

          <br> Sample No: <input type="text" name="analysis_sampleNo[]" value="<?php echo $row['analysis_sampleNo']; ?>">
          <br> Result: <input type="text" name="analysis_result[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities(number_format($row['analysis_result'], 2)); ?>">
          <br> Exceed: <input type="text" name="analysis_total[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities(number_format($row['analysis_total'], 2)); ?>" readonly>
          <br>

          <!-- Add the "Calculate" button -->
          <button type="button" onclick="calculateAnalysisTotal(this)">Calculate</button>
          <br />
          <hr />
        </div>
        <?php $a++;} ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div id="analysisContainer"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace all PHP with RELEVANT RENDERED HTML and JavaScript since this is not a PHP question

Comment: but the data that display for issue and report analysis is fetch from table.

Comment: If there is no interaction with the server needed after the page has loaded and you just want to show/hide stuff according to the checkboxes, then it is not a PHP issue. If you need to access the data from the server when you check and uncheck, then search for `php ajax checkbox`

Comment: yes i want to show/hide the data according to the checkboxes. then i want to update to the server.

Comment: We can't easily help with the checkbox part if we can't see what html the javascript is interacting with. Therefore it's much more useful to see the html produced by the php, rather than the php itself

Comment: P.S. Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. a `'` in the value would crash your query because SQL would think the `'` was terminating the input string early.

Comment: Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Comment: Thank you Adyson, i will try to modify my code again.